# Multiple values in combobox (selectbox) to the variables in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying something in my examination script. So I'd like to ask a question about my problem.

I have combobox in the exam form. like this :

```
<option value="<?PHP echo $answer_list['answer_value']; ?>"><?PHP echo $answer_list['answer_detail']; ?></option>
```

I must put another value in this. it will be like this I think:

```
<option value="<?PHP echo $answer_list['answer_value']; ?>,<?PHP echo $answer_list['answer_id']; ?>"><?PHP echo $answer_list['answer_detail']; ?></option>
```

I must save these values to the database, but I really don't know how can I save these values to the database when I exploded these values to the different columns in one table.

---

I tried something with explode function but I couldn't do it well.

So when I posted these values from form, I tried this function but I couldn't save them to the database.

```
$answers = $_POST['answers'];
$answer_explode = explode(",",$answers);
$answer_id = $answer_explode[0]; 
$answer_value = $answer_explode[1];
```

this gets only first and second value in the array. But I must make 2 variables like this :

```
before comma 
$answer_id = values before comma
$answer_value = values after comma
```

how can I do that?

Comment: So what you are saying here is you need to save these first and then get them from a database to then display in the select list?

Answer (score 2):

Name your `<option>` in HTML with the array syntax `<option name="answers[]">` and you can access them in PHP POST as an array.